# How to *really* lock the Windows 7 task bar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I generally love windows task-bar but I have one issue with it. Even when you lock it (right click > lock the taskbar), it locks various toolbars. I don't use any toolbars such as quick launch, my computer. Reason is simple, I don't need quick-launch now because task bar itself is launch bar.

So practically, locking the task bar has no real effect on my computer and I can still move the icons in the task bar around. Sometimes, I accidentally drag the icons and disturb their positions.

Is it possible to really and fully lock the task bar so that task-bar buttons are **NOT** draggable.

Answer (score 1):

Locking the task bar is supposed to stop you moving or resizing it accidentally, which it achieves.
I can see your point that it might also be useful to lock the order of the items on it, but I'm not aware of a way to do this. There were utilities for Vista which added the ability to shuffle icons around on the task bar (for open applications), maybe these would also provide the opposite effect if you change the right setting.

Answer (score 0):

May be able to lock the taskbar using Group Policy. See [this example](http://www.associatedcontent.com/video/12020/how_to_disable_the_ability_to_change.html) of how to use Group Policy to lock the start menu and task bar.